# Text not being read into variable

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Here is my code, I am supposed to read in data such as `AAABBBCCCDDD` and output `a3b3c3d3`.

I have updated the code, and now the code compiles and runs, however nothing is output. I dont know if its the way im reading data in or if the code is incorrect.

```
String text;
        FileReader data = new FileReader("input.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(data); 
        text=in.readLine();
        in.close();
        //Counter looks at length of data
        int counter=0;
        //Counter2 looks at current letter or number to make see if its the same then iterates it
        int counter2=0;
             while (text.charAt(counter)<=text.length())
            {
                while (text.charAt(counter)==text.charAt(counter2+1))
                {
                    counter2++;
                }
                System.out.println(text.charAt(counter) + counter2);
                counter=counter2;
            }
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the compilation errors.

Comment: Note that you have two close votes because you haven't shown any error messages.

Comment: I just updated everything as help from the others showed a fundamental flaw in the code.

Comment: `while (text.charAt(counter)<=text.length())` looks suspicious, kind of like you didn't put much thought in to what it should do. Why would a loop continue until a char in a String is greater than its length?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the compiler is complaining is because in this loop:

```
    while (in.readLine()!=null)
    {
     text = in.readLine(); 
    }
```

it's possible that the body of the loop will never get executed, which means it's possible that `text` will never be set to anything.  And the Java compiler doesn't like it when you use a variable that may not have been set to anything.

But the whole loop is wrong anyway.  You're only using one input string, so why is this a loop?  Before we can help fix this problem, we need to know what you're trying to accomplish.  And if you really do want a loop, it would be wrong to call `in.readLine()` twice as you have above, since that means it will read *two* lines each time through the loop.

Comment: Yeah the input text might be several strings in the form of

  AABCD
  AAABB
  CBBFE

So I want to read in all the data. Do I need to do it such that its an array and work from there?

Comment: What do you want to do with your several strings?  Do you want to do your computation on each string, or do you want to concatenate them all together and then do your computation?  If it's the first one, you probably just need to move the computation into the first `while` loop.  Read a line, do the computation, print output, then loop back and read the next line.

Comment: This.... is actually the most simplistic thing ever. I will try and get back to you

Comment: I updated the code as I reread the requirements and its a continues string not several so I changed it for it for that. Now it is compelling but not outputting anything

Comment: @user3339579 see Radiodef's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've properly imported all the `java.io` classes, here are the two problems causing compilation to fail:

```
String text;
```

This must be initialized to something. Such as

```
String text = null;
```

*Possibly* setting it in the while loop is not good enough.

The other problem is this variable, `output` doesn't exist anywhere, which is why this line won't compile:

```
System.out.println(output);
```

I think you mean for it to be `text`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that and took it out. I tried the null thing too and it just got mad with a null point exception in the compiler.

Comment: These two problems I mention only get you far enough to compile. @ajb discusses other problems you may have, once you do get it to compile.

Comment: `NullPointerException`s are thrown at runtime. The compiler has nothing to do with exceptions. If it's resulting in an NPX, then that means you're never setting it to anything appropriate.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that and updated based on ajbs coments. Still now its not outputing anything. Turns out its was only a single long string i need to compress